# Does order of breakpoints matter in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using Bootstrap for three or four months now. I am always using such a sequence of endpoints, for example:

```
<div class="col-xxl-5 col-md-7 col-12"></div>
```

So, in sequence I mean that I am starting from large screen size and then to mobile version. But in many Bootstrap Templates I see an opposite, for example:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-7 col-xxl-5"></div>
```

With Bootstrap, does it matter which sequence I will use and if yes, which practice is better and why?

Thank you!

Comment: See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/extend/approach and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#core-concepts. By ordering your classes smallest-first the cascade (including omitted breakpoints) is more clear and intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap believes in mobile first responsive design, they start building components on smallest breakpoint and then layers on styles to adjust that design for larger devices, so they start with col-12 and end with col-xxl-5. In short order doesn't matter, its a good practice if you use the order as specified by them.

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-7 col-xxl-5"></div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#core-concepts